# Centos 7 Selinux issue I think? php cannot read or write

Tags: php, permissions, selinux

I have an uploads folder for my web application: `/disk2/app/uploads`.

ls -Z returns:

```
drw-r--r--. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 uploads
```

`ls -Z /` returns:

```
drwxrwxrwx. root root system_u:object_r:file_t:s0      disk2
```

`ls -Z /disk2` returns:

```
drwxr-xr-x. apache    apache    unconfined_u:object_r:file_t:s0  app
```

much of which I got from [here](https://blog.lysender.com/2015/07/centos-7-selinux-php-apache-cannot-writeaccess-file-no-matter-what/)

when I run `is_writable('/disk2/app/uploads')` in php it returns `false`

I have tried every possibility I can think of to figure it out.

Relevant audit logs:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1510944045.012:202923): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=14017 comm="httpd" path="/disk2/app/uploads/12222/206/1496103427-20170526_151922.jpg" dev=sdb ino=17826039 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:file_t:s0 tclass=file
type=AVC msg=audit(1510944045.012:202924): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=14017 comm="httpd" name="uploads" dev=sdb ino=2097155 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:file_t:s0 tclass=dir
```

Comment: Are there any relevant 'AVC denied' messages in /var/log/audit/audit.log?

Comment: And what about `/disk2`?

Comment: @user430214 See my edits above.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I added the output of ls -Z above.  Do the parent directories matter if the ownership etc. is good on the child?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looks like subdirectories are being created with the wrong file context. Did you have your policy match everything underneath that path?

Comment: I modified the context of uploads based on that article I referenced.  I am farther into the weeds with Selinux than I understand.

Comment: Does anyone know what the context should look like so the apache user can read and write from this directory?

Comment: Your directory is not executable!

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure SELinux file contexts so that they are correctly set when files are created. Files in general, inherit the fcontext of their parent directory so you need to specify that correctly. Something like

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/disk2/app/uploads(/.*)?"
restorecon -Rv /disk2/app/uploads
```

should to the trick.